# Can I cast a generic type reference (EntityInterface) of an object, to a more specific, AccountInterface, if I know the object is a user?

Tags: users, 9

Here is my code

```
// implements hook_node_presave
function mymodule_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {

  if ( $entity->getEntityTypeId() === 'user'  ) {
```

so now I know the $entity is a user, can I then do:

```
  $user = (AccountInterface)$entity;  // type-casting: a generic type down to a more specific one
```

so that I have the methods (functions) that the AccountInterface provides specifically for querying the contents of the user object, e.g. `getRoles`

Is this the correct Drupal convention, to do that PHP type casting?  I'm familiar with it also in C++ and Java.

If it isn't the convention, then how would one be able to invoke method(s) functions that one should expect to be available, on that object?

I suppose I could get another copy of the object using the id of the entity, which has the more specific reference interface but that seems wasteful, if I already have the object in `$entity`.

Overall, I'm trying to do something with the User object that is available from the hook parameter. I don't want to use current user, because what I want to do is for another user that has been created and modified/updated, so I need to work with the user passed via `$entity`

Comment: You mean from the IDE? You would hint it's type to the editor via code comment to provide that assistance. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1819269

Comment: Sorry Kevin, no, not from the IDE. This is just for code executing. The hook has given me an object, `$entity` but the type is very generic - `EntityInterface`.  But I know from calling `$entity->getEntityTypeId()` that it's a 'user' so therefore, can I cast the object to an interface that inherits from `EntityInterface` e.g. `AccountInterface` to be able to use more specific functions on the object. Do you know what I mean by casting (type-casting)?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the theory: Given `class User implements EntityInterface` and `function hook_foo(EntityInterface $bar)` and `$a = new User(); hook_foo($a);` then $bar still IS a user object inside the hook, no need to typecast. You (and the IDE) just don't know which specific object it will be passed at runtime, but it will use the EntityInterface as common ground.

Comment: The passed object is an instance of EntityInterface, it isn't literally that object. The application knows what concrete object it is, the IDE doesn't. Once you know (from above) type hint it via comment and the IDE will be able to know what methods are available.

Comment: @Hudri if $entity is a class User which I believe it to be because getEntityTypeId gives 'user' then I know that getRoles is a function that is in User class. But I don't think I can do $entity->getRoles() directly because $entity is EntityInterface which doesn't have getRoles. So I need to cast $entity to User.

Comment: @Hudri would you be able to post an answer here please, so show how you would use the getRoles() function (which belongs to User) on $entity ?

Comment: You are already doing it correctly :-) you just don't need to typecast. You get any EntityInterface as common ground in the hook (could be Node, could be User, could be Term,...) But BEFORE you do any user-specific thing (like `getRoles()`) inside the hook, you must make sure that the specific object is of type EntityInterface (which is granted) AND of type User (which is optional and which you have done by checking `$entity->getEntityTypeId() === 'user'`)

Comment: @Kevin this is not related to the IDE at all, this is for when the code is executing. The reference to the object is of type EntityInterface but the actual object is User I believe ( getEntityTypeId gives 'user' ). So I want to know if I can cast $entity as User. EntityInterface is just an interface to that object which is User one can't instantiate objects from interfaces.

Comment: @Hudri ah thankyou - I'll try it. I know in C++ and Java one had to cast the object first, so I'm guessing with PHP that's not necessary as it's automatic.

Comment: The cast is not necessary to make methods available - the interpreter will simply apply the requested method to the object at run time, and throw an error if it's not found. The best way to check is at language level, i.e. `if ($entity instanceof AccountInterface)`

Comment: +1 thank you Clive and thank you Hudri. Please post answers for your comments here if you like and I will upvote both. I'll accept Hudri's comment as they came in first. And yes - I just checked - and it works fine - no need for cast.

Comment: Will try to a bit later - BTW another way to approach this is with `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave`, e.g. `function mymodule_user_presave(AccountInterface $account) { ...`, which would eliminate the question altogether!

Comment: Thank you additionally Clive - the instanceof tip and general php mechanism is enlightening. As for `function mymodule_user_presave(AccountInterface $account)` I didn't know it had that specific a type, so I can see what you mean. I will bear that in mind!

Comment: Yes, PHP isn't a statically typed language. so it won't tell you you cannot call `getRoles()` because of how the parameter is defined.